# How do I use paging in a content type containing a paragraph?

Tags: 8, paging, paragraphs

I created a content type with just one **multivalue** field which turns to be an "entity type revisions" (i.e. Paragraphs).

I would like to have paging working on this setup (when number of Paragraphs exceeds some quantity) but just creating a view with paging does not work as the "pageable" content is the content type itself, not its fields.

Having Paragraphs as a standalone content type is a no-go as I do not want to have them scattered in the content section.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a view for paragraphs and place it in the content type with an EVA display  [(Entity Views Attachment)](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva).

To do this add a EVA display, connect it to the node entity (content) and bundle (content type) in the Entity Content Settings, select as Arguments the ID of the entity the view is attached to and add a contextual filter for the parent id.

Now the view appears as field in the content type and you can use the pager from the view for the paragraphs inside of the field.

Comment: I followed your instructions but I guess I must be missing something. I would like to show you some screenshots of what I have done but comments do not let me to attach them. Answering myself would let me to attach those screenshots but it seems it is not the way to go as per StackExchange policy. What do you suggest?